# Is there a name for this expression? $\frac{|x-y|}{\max(x,y)}$

Tags: functions, notation

Sorry if this is noob-ish, but I was doing some really basic analysis between two data-sets and saw this was used as a way to calculate a sort of "normalized difference" (deviation?) between the old and new values.  Again, my apologies for not using the mathematically correct terminology.

In Excel (because that's where I found it), using cells `A1` and `B1` for example, it's `ABS(A1-B1)/MAX(A1,B1)`.  In [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=abs(x-y)%2Fmax(x,y)) it's `Abs[x - y]/Max[x, y]`.  Formally:

$$\frac{|x-y|}{\max(x,y)}$$

Is there a name/precedent for this, maybe in the realm of statistics or analytics, or is it just something the guy before me made up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a specific case of [relative difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference#Definitions).

Comment: Awesome, thank you sir!

Comment: Glad to help.${}$